# SQL - Trying to tell which part of a query was matched with an 'OR' statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I want to check if multiple columns match what I'm looking for, like so:

```
$params = [$param1,$param2];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

In this example I'm ust using two columns but on my site I've got 8 and this could increase.

But I want to echo out the data from the column that matches and not the other columns.

So logically speaking I want something like: if column1 matches my params echo column1 else if column2 matches my params echo column2.

Will I need to do a query for each of these individually or is there a way to tell when you have an 'OR' statement like in the query above which part of the query is being matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union` , According to your demand your query should be like below

```
   SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ?
    union
   SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column2 LIKE ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a single column, I'd go with the `UNION` approach described in another answer here.

If you want something to embed in a wider query, you may be well served by a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN column1 LIKE ? THEN column1
       WHEN column2 LIKE ? THEN column2
                           ELSE   NULL   END    AS newColumn
FROM
  table
WHERE
     column1 LIKE ?
  OR column2 LIKE ?
```

*(Both suggestions **assume** that column1 and column2 are the same datatype.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow multiple rows to match, then you can use `union all` as in:

```
select 'column1' as which, column1 
from t 
where column1 like ?
union all
select 'column2' as which, column2 
from t 
where column2 like ?;
```

Or, if performance is not a big deal and you only want to list the condition once:

```
select which, val
from (select 'column1' as which, column1 as val
      from t
      union all 
      select 'column2' as which, column2 
      from t 
     ) t
where val like ?;
```

This lists each match on a separate row.  I would be inclined, though, to list them in a single row:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 case when column1 like ? then 'column1' end,
                 case when column2 like ? then 'column1' end
                )
from t
where column1 like ? or column2 like ?;
```

In this case, duplicating the conditions can be cumbersome, so you can also do:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 case when column1 like ? then 'column1' end,
                 case when column2 like ? then 'column1' end
                ) as matches
from t
where matches > '';
```